# How to change Column Text in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using Gridview to display data from database can any body show me how to change column name here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yccwebportalConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            string me = "select doc_name, doc_isvalid,doc_nextrenewdate,DATEDIFF(d, doc_nextrenewdate, GETDATE()) as Difference from tbldocstatus";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(me, con);
            con.Open();
            GridView2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView2.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Width="753px">

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that in GridView's [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event which is triggered for every `GridViewRow`after it was databound.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Date";
    }
}
```

or you can set [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to `false` and add the columns declaratively on aspx:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1"
   onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
   autogeneratecolumns="False"
   emptydatatext="No data available."
     runat="server">
       <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="DateField" HeaderText="Date" 
             SortExpression="DateField" /> 
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Databound event handler type this:

```
GridView2.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Your preferred text"
```

Column[0] is your the column index of the column you want to change

Answer (score 0):

Give aliases to your columns which are returned and they will be set as your column name. For e.g

```
string me = "select doc_name as 'Document Name', doc_isvalid as 'Is Valid' 
from tbldocstatus";
```

`Document Name` and `Is Valid` will be your column name.

Answer (score 0):

try this :**DGVArchive** is the name of gridview

```
DGVArchive.Columns[0].HeaderText = "text 1";
DGVArchive.Columns[1].HeaderText = "text2";
```